# gzcompress won't produce a valid zipped file?

Tags: php, gzip

Consider this:

```
$text = "hello";
$text_compressed = gzcompress($text, 6);
$success = file_put_contents('file.gz', $text_compressed);
```

When i try to open file.gz, i get errors. How can i open file.gz under terminal without calling php? (using gzuncompress works just fine!)

*I can't recode every file i did, since that i now have almost a Billion files encoded this way!* So if there is a solution... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you don't really have gzipped files. To open your files from a terminal you need the [uncompress](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/uncompress/) utility.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`gzencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) instead.

Luckily for you, the fix is easy: just write a script that opens each of your files one by one, uses `gzuncompress()` to uncompress that file, and then writes that file back out with `gzencode()` instead of `gzcompress()`, repeating the process for all of the files.

Alternatively (since you said you "didn't want to recode your files"), you could use [`uncompress`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/uncompress/) to open the existing files from the command line (instead of `gunzip`/`zcat`).

---

As noted on the [`gzcompress()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php):

> #### gzcompress
>
> This is ***not*** the same as gzip compression, which includes some header data. See gzencode() for gzip compression.

Comment: Since he doesn't want to recode every billion file, it's going to be fun.

Comment: Indeed. But he might have just meant that he didn't want to re-*create* each file's uncompressed contents. Hopefully. :)